# .NET Maui: Reading Maui assets from unit tests

Tags: .net, maui, xunit

I'm having some difficulties reading a json file in my xUnit test.
Reading the file in the simulator or on device works fine but not from the unit tests where I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException
> : This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of
> this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main
> application project in order to reference the platform-specific
> implementation.
>
> Stack Trace: 
> FileSystemImplementation.PlatformOpenAppPackageFileAsync(String
> filename) FileSystemImplementation.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(String
> filename)

The JSON file is located in `/Resources/Raw/contacts.json` and set as a MAUI Asset.

I have a function in my viewModel which reads and parses the JSON file:

```
public async Task LoadContacts()
{
    using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("contacts.json");
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string contents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    List<Contact> distributors = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Contact>>(contents);
}
```

This is my test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestLoadContacts()
{
    var viewModel = new ContactsPageViewModel();
    await viewModel.LoadContacts();
}
```

I've added `UseMaui` and Maui references to the xUnit project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Essentials" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The MAUI project is built as .NET 8.0 library and my other unit tests are working fine.

Does anyone know how to read the files when accessed from the tests?
Thanks.